# Typo3 extension: how to build a extension to load image/media from my cloud site

Tags: typo3

i want to implement a Typo3 extension: load image/media from my cloud site, and insert into Typo3 web page.

but i am a very new comer of Typo3. i want to learn how to build my extension. could someone tell me the guideline or a sample extension which is similiar as my extension? i read Typo3 site, but it hard to understand and the sample extension do not match my extension purpose, so i can not refer it much.

the extension features are:

1. i have a DAM(Digital Assets Management) system to store lots of images/medias. i want to use OAuth protocol to connect to my DAM system. so my extension should plug in someplace to let me connect to my OAuth site. on that setting page, i should able to input my OAuth APP_ID, APP_Secret, then i should to open a dialog to connect to my OAuth site, and input my account info. later, i should be able to store the OAuth access token in some DB.
2. i want my extension appear in some places in Typo3, wherever i can insert a image/media. whenever user want to insert a image/media, the extension will launch a page/frame to my DAM system, and i can choose a image to insert into Typo3 page.

please see my attached picture "screen1.PNG", [screen1.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXeVI.png). when i create a image element in Typo3 site, in the Images tab/section, it has 2 buttons "Add Image" and "Select & upload files", here i guess my extension should create the 3rd button named "From Cloud". please see attached "screen2.PNG". [screen2.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45VFa.png). this new "From Cloud" button is used to show all my images/medias on my DAM system. and when user click this button, it will popup up a dialog, please see attached "screen3.PNG". [screen3.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq6Yy.png). that popup dialog will show all images/medias on my DAM system, and let user select some images, and insert into current Typo3 page. this dialog contains a folder tree on left panel, to show my DAM structure. the dialog show all images/medias on right panel. it also has some Typo3 own button to insert images into web page.

because i am very new comer for Typo3, read https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/1-the-example-extension.html is already hard for me. the major block is how to insert the "From Cloud" button in Typo3 own page.

could someone give me suggestion/guideline about my extension? or a similiar extension to let me download and study?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I never had to solve this task I just can give you a direction where to search.

In your TYPO3 instance you will have a filelist module. There is the place where you have to connect with your cloud system.

Look with the WEB->LIST module on the root page for the file storages. You will find the "File list". If you open it you can see a select box called "driver". Per default TYPO3 contains just the driver "Local file system". You must find a way to add a driver for your cloud storage. If successful, you can add a second file storage to your system which will be connected to your server.

Comment: thanks giving me clue.
do you know from where i can get the "driver" extension doc?

Answer (score 0):

I would point your eyes at the term [FAL Adapters](https://wiki.typo3.org/FAL_Adapters). They make it possible to have your cloud at the `Filelist` module. Take an look at the other FAL Adapters to make you own one. One Finished you can use all you files in your cloud as they are directly uploaded in TYPO3.

Comment: thanks for the clue. i looked at the FAL page, and find most of them are out of date. do you know where i can obtain this FAL extension development doc? thanks again.